# JComboBox how to compute for two integers from two JComboBox and have the result in a JTextfield when clicking the JButton

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have 2 `JComboBox` consisting of numbers `combobox1= 1 to 5` and c`ombobox2= 1 to 6.`

and when I click my `JButton`, I want the two chosen numbers to be added and shown on a `Textfield.`

I already have the complete code except for the calculation and how to have the result in the `textfield.`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class exer1 extends JFrame{

    JFrame form = new JFrame ("haay");
    JButton btn = new JButton ("Compute");
    JTextField txt = new JTextField (10); 
    JComboBox cb1 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox cb2 = new JComboBox();


public exer1(){

    form.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    form.setSize (500,550);

    form.getContentPane().add(txt);
    form.getContentPane().add(btn);
    form.getContentPane().add(cb1);
    form.getContentPane().add(cb2);

    cb1.addItem(new Integer(1));
    cb1.addItem(new Integer(2));
    cb1.addItem(new Integer(3));
    cb1.addItem(new Integer(4));
    cb1.addItem(new Integer(5));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(1));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(2));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(3));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(4));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(5));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(6));

    txt.setBounds(150,90,100,30);
    btn.setBounds(40,170,100,40);
    cb1.setBounds(190,140,50,30);
    cb2.setBounds(190,190,50,30);

    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){


            }
        });



  form.show();

}




    public static void main (String args []){
        exer1 xx = new exer1();

    }

}
```

Please help.

Comment: The Swing tutorial [How to use combo boxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) explains how to do all of this -- use the method `getSelectedItem()`. What have you tried? And don't give us a due date please. That is your problem not ours.

Comment: Carol, in the future, use the "homework" tag.  Everybody knows anyways and most people are more eager to help somebody who is up front.  :)

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 4):

The [sscce](http://sscce.org/) provided is clearly homework, but the goal of the exercise is not so clear. A few things are worth noting.

1. The GUI should be constructed on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
2. By convention, class names begin with an initial capital letter.
3. Lengthy initialization should be factored for readability.
4. The objects added to each `JComboBox` are instances of the class [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html), which model a subset of the mathematical integers. Note why [`valueOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28int%29) "should generally be used in preference to the constructor."
5. There's no need to convert anything to a `String` until it's time to update the display in `actionPerformed()`. Because [`getSelectedItem()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) returns a value of type `Object`, the result must be cast to `Integer`; this is perfectly safe in the context of locally constructed data.
6. Once the `Integer` values have been recovered, it's easy to obtain the sum as an `int` value.
7. The final conversion of the `sum` to a [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) is left as an exercise. Hint: [`String`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) has a suitable method, the name of which may now seem familiar.
8. It's never too soon to become friends with [*A Visual Guide to Layout Managers*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

[image]

Revised example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Exercise1 extends JFrame {

    JFrame form = new JFrame("Exercise1");
    JButton btn = new JButton("Compute");
    JTextField txt = new JTextField(10);
    JComboBox<Integer> cb1 = new JComboBox<>();
    JComboBox<Integer> cb2 = new JComboBox<>();

    public Exercise1() {
        form.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        form.add(txt);
        form.add(btn);
        form.add(cb1);
        form.add(cb2);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            cb1.addItem(Integer.valueOf(i));
            cb2.addItem(Integer.valueOf(i));
        }
        cb2.addItem(new Integer(6));
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Integer v1 = (Integer) cb1.getSelectedItem();
                Integer v2 = (Integer) cb2.getSelectedItem();
                int sum = v1.intValue() + v2.intValue();
                txt.setText("42"); // really should convert sum to a String
            }
        });

        form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        form.pack();
        form.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Exercise1 exercise1 = new Exercise1();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For reference, Java 7 introduces [`ComboBoxModel<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) for improved type safely, although `getSelectedItem()` remains backward compatible.

Answer (score 3):

I've kind of rewritten the entire script (sorry for any inconvenience)...

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class exer1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
    JLabel first = new JLabel("Select the first number:", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JComboBox fNum = new JComboBox();
    JPanel row2 = new JPanel();
    JLabel second = new JLabel("Select the second number:", JLabel.RIGHT);
    JComboBox sNum = new JComboBox();
    JPanel row3 = new JPanel();
    JButton comp = new JButton("Compute");
    JTextField total = new JTextField(5);

    public exer1() {
        super("Calculator");
        row1.add(first);
        fNum.addItem("1");
        fNum.addItem("2");
        fNum.addItem("3");
        fNum.addItem("4");
        fNum.addItem("5");
        fNum.addItem("6");
        row1.add(fNum);
        add(row1);
        row2.add(second);
        sNum.addItem("1");
        sNum.addItem("2");
        sNum.addItem("3");
        sNum.addItem("4");
        sNum.addItem("5");
        sNum.addItem("6");
        row2.add(sNum);
        add(row2);
        comp.addActionListener(this);
        row3.add(comp);
        total.setEditable(false);
        row3.add(total);
        add(row3);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(500, 550);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(fNum.getSelectedItem().toString());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sNum.getSelectedItem().toString());
        total.setText("" + (num1 + num2));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        exer1 xx = new exer1();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see that `Integer.parseInt()` won't throw `NumberFormatException` because only valid `Integer` instances are present, but this seems convoluted.

Comment: @trashgod Convoluted in what way?

Comment: Converting `Integer` to `String` and then parsing it.

Comment: Not at all. You answer precedes my own, and I would encourage that it be accepted. Feel free to incorporate any features of my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695062/jcombobox-how-to-compute-for-two-integers-from-two-jcombobox-and-have-the-result/7700374#7700374) in your answer. `"" + …` has never appealed to me, but it's a common idiom. +1 for using a layout, btw.

Comment: Opps, my mistake: you're adding `String` to the combo, not `Integer`. Also, needs a `this.add(row2);`.

Answer (score -1):

use `form.setVisible(true);`

then:

```
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int cb1Int = Integer.parseInt(cb1.getSelectedItem().toString());
            int cb2Int = Integer.parseInt(cb2.getSelectedItem().toString());
            txt.setText(String.valueOf(cb1Int + cb2Int));
        }
    });
```

Good luck with your homework.  ;)

Comment: The items are already Integer objects, so no need to make then Strings and then parse then to int. Just cast the objects returned from `getSelectedItem()` to Integer. And better she tries to figure this out on her own first.

Comment: Yes you are right about casting, but I tend avoid casting out of principle.  I don't really agree that you need to rake the kid over the coals for 3 lines of code.  She pretty clearly wrote the rest, it's terrible.  ;) :P

Comment: It's fine as written.  I virtually never cast objects in my own projects, as I consider it bad form.  It is certainly not required here.

Comment: hey, the numbers required just increased up to 100.                   cb2.addItem(new Integer(1));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(2));
    cb2.addItem(new Integer(3));...and i cant really code this for another 10 JComboBox with numbers up to 100. i need your expertise again @Eric Lindauer. please. your code doesn't work everytime change the later to  cb1.addItem(new Integer (1,2,3)); any codes for numbers 1 to 100 in a combobox, not calling them one by one? :(

Comment: @CarolKate: clarify your problem by editing your original post as we cannot read any code posted in a comment. And ***please*** first show us your attempt to solve the new problem, else you'll only be cheating yourself.

Comment: @CarolKate: or not. up to you.