# Convert Actionlistener type to integer java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I need to convert an `Actionlistener` type to an integer to call a method.
Any ideas?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**
* sold by pound
*/
public class CandyPanel extends JPanel { 
    public CandyPanel () {
        // Create a GridLayout manager with 
        // two rows and one column.
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        // Create the radio buttons.
        JPanel gummyBears = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        // Add a border around the panel.
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Gummy Bears"));

        // Add the JPanel to the panel.
        add(gummyBears);
    }

    /** 
    * returns the total cost of the item based on the 
    * number of units purchased 
    * @param number    the number of units purchased 
    * @return          the total cost of those units 
    */
    public double getCost(int number) { 
         double total = number * 2.00;
         return total;
    } 

    /** 
    * Prints the ordered item 
    * @param amount    the number of units purchased 
    * @param cost      the total cost of those units 
    */
    public void printOrderItem(int amount, double cost){ 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, amount + " Gummy Bears at $2.00/pound = $" + cost + ".");
    } 
}
```

This is the method which will require the converted `int`.

```
public double getCost(int number) { 
     double total = number * 2.00;
     return total;
}
```

I tried doing `parseInt` as researched online but it does not work with `ActionEvent`.

Comment: `e` is not a string.  Where is the integer value supposed to come from?

Comment: Yes I do realize it is not a String. 
The integer value is supposed to come what the user inputs.
I will ask how much of whatever is needed and user  will give me input. Problem is, ActionEvent is the listener, so I wish to have a temporary value that stores the parsed ActionEvent type.
Would getText() work?

Comment: Where is that input supposed to go?  Is there a text box somewhere?  At the moment, there's no place anywhere in the code you've provided that mentions how the user inputs the number.

Comment: I'll update the code to show all of what is in that class specifically.
Edit: updated.

Comment: ..This updated code still has nowhere for the user to put the number.  You're going to need a text box or a dialog box or somewhere for the user to type.

Comment: Have you tried `Double.valueOf()`?

Comment: Ok I'm sorry for wasting your time, I didn't realize this.
My bad.

Comment: @trashgod: No, I'll try doing that.

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7700374/230513).

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an ActionEvent to an int. But if it is the user input you want convert to an int say a text box it would be something like this:

```
String s = jTextBox.getText();
int i = Integer.valueOf(s);
```

And then plug the integer value into your method.
There is also a tutorial on how to use an ActionListener here if you need help: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Hope this helps!